# Does the cubic Hermite spline interpolation of a monotone data with known slopes guarantee the monotonicity in interpolation segments?

Tags: interpolation, spline, piecewise-continuity

I am trying to interpolate monotone data with known data values and also known first derivative values at knots. If I used these values with cubic Hermite spline interpolation, Can I guarantee the monotonicity of the interpolation segments?

Comment: Cannot answer, depends on the given slopes.

Comment: As noted, the condition of being $C^2$ forces you to sacrifice monotonicity in your cubic spline. That being said, there are $C^2$ *rational* interpolants that also possess monotonicity. You might try researching about them if this is of interest.

Answer (score 1):

No, straightforward Hermite cubic interpolation does not guarantee monotonicity. However, there are other piecewise polynomial interpolation methods that do preserve monotonicity. Look up terms like "monotone spline" or "monotone interpolation". Here is one reference, which describes the [Fritsch-Carlson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation).